# ' vectors must be the same length' error

Tags: matlab, scatter

I've got a 250 x 250 image, I want to have a scatter plot of the intensity of every pixel and its nearest neighborhood. This is my code:

```
I = imread(image);
i = [1,249];
j = [1,250];
X = I(i,j);
Y = I(i+1,j);
scatter(X,Y);
```

why do I get the " X and Y vectors must be the same length" error? They are the same length !

Answer (score 1):

Because `scatter(X, Y)` is only used for vectors, not matrix. In your example, both X and Y are 2x2 matrices, not vectors.

From its [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html):

> scatter(X,Y) displays circles at the locations specified by the vectors X and Y. This type of graph is also known as a bubble plot.

---

**Edit:** if you want to plot matrix, use `plotmatrix()` instead:

```
plotmatrix(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scatter(X,Y) is used only for vectors as herohuyongtao correctly mentioned. You could try to do the following:

```
m = 250;
X = I(m+1:end);
Y = I(1:end-m);
scatter(X,Y);
```

You convert your image matrix I into a vector X while ignoring the first column and in a vector Y while ignoring the last column. X(n) is thus the neighbour of Y(n) on the right side.

I hope this helps!